# How to implement a hold-out validation in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, caret

Let's say I'm using the `Sonar` data and I'd like to make a hold-out validation in R. I partitioned the data using the `createFolds` from `caret` package as `folds <- createFolds(mydata$Class, k=5)`.

I would like then to use exactly the fold `mydata[i]` as test data and train a classifier using `mydata[-i]` as train data.

My first thought was to use the `train` function, but I couldn't find any support for hold-out validation. I mean, I don't want to partition my data and then test all the combinations for estimating the mean accuracy, I want to train it only once. Am I missing something here?

Also, I'd like to be able to use exactly the pre-defined folds as parameter, instead of letting the function partition the data. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are interested in. If it is a single hold-out, you can use

```
trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = .8, number = 1)
```

and 80% will be used for training.

There is also `method = "none"` that will just fit the model for a single tuning parameter value (using the entire training set).

Also, if you want to use your own hold-out set(s), see the `index` argument of `trainControl`.

Max

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot, @topepo, and great job with the package! I noted, however, that if i pass an index with the method="knn", it gives an error. Is that expected?