# When not to use cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, cross-validation

As I read through the site most answers suggest that cross validation should be done in machine learning algorithms. However as I was reading through the book "Understanding Machine Learning" I saw there is an exercise that sometimes it's better not to use cross validation. I'm really confused. When training algorithm on the whole data is better than cross-validation? Does it happen in real data-sets?

> Let $H_1,...,H_k$ be k hypothesis classes. Suppose you are given $m$ i.i.d. training examples and you would like to learn the class $H=\cup^k_{i=1}H_i$. Consider two alternative approaches:
>
> 1. Learn $H$ on the $m$ examples using the ERM rule
> 2. Divide the m examples into a training set of size $(1−\alpha)m$ and a validation set of size $\alpha m$, for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Then, apply the approach of model selection using validation. That is, ﬁrst train each class $H_i$ on the $(1−\alpha)m$ training examples using the ERM rule with respect to $H_i$,and let $\hat{h}_1,\ldots,\hat{h}_k$ be the resulting hypotheses. Second, apply the ERM rule with respect to the ﬁnite class {$\hat{h}_1,\ldots,\hat{h}_k$} on the $\alpha m$ validation examples.
>
> Describe scenarios in which the ﬁrst method is better than the second and vice versa.

[Image of the quastion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPm9n.png).

Comment: It's an interesting exercise, but I don't agree with the label.  I think cross validation is doing its job perfectly here.  As a tangential, it would really be preferred if you typed out the exercise and cited it, as opposed to attaching an image.  The image is inaccessible to vision impaired users.

Comment: One possible drawback to using cross-validation could be over-fitting (as in the case of leave out one cross validation). Essentially, by using cross validation techniques, we are tuning the parameters of the model on validation data set (and not on test dataset). But sometimes, this tuning could go a bit too much resulting in possible over-fit when the classifier is tested on the test set.

Comment: What does "parity" mean here?

Comment: @shadowtalker I think it means summation modulo 2.

Comment: Do you differentiate between (repeated) cross-validation and bootstrapping?

Comment: Hmm.  From the original post with the picture I thought you were asking abut the *first* question.  cbeleites answered the second.  Are you still interested in the first question from the image?

Comment: @MatthewDrury Sure. I've just asked it in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320237/127220).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take-home-messages:

- the excercise *should* teach you that it is sometimes (depending on your field: often or even almost always) better not to do data-driven model optimization/tuning/selection.
- There are also [situations where cross validation is not the best choice among the different validation options](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/104713/4598), but these considerations are not relevant in the context of your excercise here.
- And not validating (verifying, testing) your model is *never* a good choice.

---

Unfortunately, the text you cite changes two things between approach 1 and 2:

- Approach 2 performs cross validation **and** data-driven model selection/tuning/optimization
- Approach 1 neither uses cross validation, nor data-driven model selection/tuning/optimization.
- Approach 3 cross validation without data-driven model selection/tuning/optimization is perfectly feasible (amd IMHO would lead to more insight) in the context discussed here
- Approach 4, no cross validation but data-driven model selection/tuning/optimization is possible as well, but more complex to construct.

IMHO, cross validation and data-driven optimization are two totally different (and largely independent) decisions in setting up your modeling strategy. The *only* connection is that you can use cross validation estimates as target functional for your optimization. But there exist other target functionals ready to be used, and there are other uses of cross validation estimates (importantly, you can use them for verification of your model, aka validation or testing)

Unfortunately, machine learning terminology is IMHO currently a mess which suggests false connections/causes/dependencies here.

- When you look up approach 3 (cross validation not for optimization but for measuring model performance), you'll find the "decision" cross validation vs. training on the whole data set to be a false dichotomy in this context: When using cross validation to measure classifier performance, the cross validation figure of merit is used as estimate for a model trained on the whole data set. I.e. approach 3 includes approach 1.
- Now, let's look at the 2nd decision: data-driven model optimization or not. This is IMHO the crucial point here. And yes, there are real world situations where *not* doing data-driven model optimization is better. Data-driven model optimization comes at a cost. You can think of it this way: the information in your data set is used to estimate not only the $p$ parameters/coefficients of the model, but what the optimization does is estimating further parameters, the so-called hyperparameters. If you describe the model fitting and optimiztion/tuning process as a search for the model parameters, then this hyperparameter optimization means that a vastly larger search space is considered. In other words, in approach 1 (and 3) you restrict the search space by specifiying those hyperparameters. Your real world data set may be large enough (contain enough information) to allow fitting within that restricted search space, but not large enough to fix all parameters sufficiently well in the larger search space of approaches 2 (and 4).

In fact, in my field I very often have to deal with data sets that far too small to allow any thought of data-driven optimization. So what do I do instead: I use my domain knowledge about the data and data generating processes to decide which model matches well with the physical nature of data and application. And within these, I still have to restrict my model complexity.

Comment: Nice answer.  I somehow hoped you would contributed to this thread. Obvious +1

Comment: Thank you for your informative and helpful answer. What I learned from your answer is that we may choose approach 2 when we have small data sets not because of validation but because of model selection. Am I correct? Does Using model selection for small data sets somehow lead to underfitting?

Comment: Another question is that in the exercise the size of hypothesis class is the same for both approach 1 and 2. How the search space is larger in that case for approach 2?

Comment: Well, if there is a choice in 2 and not in 1 then the search space in 2 is larger. If the search space in 2 is not larger, then there's really nothing to select in approach 2. My answer and interpretation of what approach 2 means is triggered by the term "model selection using validation". If the context is still the one of the "when does cross validation fail" excercise before the one in question here, then the book may mean what I called approach 3 above, i.e. no model selection involved. But in that case, the words model selection really should not be there. I cannot judge how likely this..

Comment: ... is as I don't know what the book says about model selection, nor what their ERM rule is  (in my vocabulary, ERM expands to enterprise risk management...). However, my answer holds regardless of the modeling algorithm.

Comment: I think you are correct and the emphasis here should be on model selection and this question is different from the first exercise. But I still don't understand how the search space here is larger. ERM stands for empirical risk minimization and is simply finding a hypothesis that minimizes the loss function on the training data.