# Failure of k-fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-selection, model-evaluation

There is an interesting exercise which shows k-fold cross validation fails in some cases. The exercise is as follows:

Consider a case in that the label is chosen at random according to $P[y =1]= P[y =0]=1/2$. Consider a learning algorithm that outputs the constant predictor $h(x)=1$ if the parity of the labels on the training set is 1 and otherwise the algorithm outputs the constant predictor $h(x)=0$. Prove that the difference between the leave-one-out estimate and the true error in such a case is always 1/2.

My question is in what cases (or under what conditions) k-fold cross validation fails? Is it only k-fold validation that fails or other types of cross validation may fail too?

Comment: Cross validation fails whenever there's a dependency between samples. This kind of dependency exists in the scenario you provided as well as other scenarios, such as time dependent samples (time series), samples that originally belong to a group out of a set and more.

Comment: @Omri374 I think in the example there is no dependency between samples. Samples are i.i.d

Comment: The dependency here is not between samples, but between runs of the CV algorithm, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Omri374 there is always dependency in CV, as long as there are overlapping samples between different folds. That is not a problem of CV.

Comment: @Lii I agree. I was referring to the example provided in the question, in which the model is heavily dependent on the subset of training samples. A change in one sample would change the output of the model even if the number of samples is high.

Comment: @SMA.D: does the text give an explanation what they consider a failure of the validation plan?

Comment: @cbeleites I think they consider PAC learning framework. Which is in brief: for any distribution of the data (unknown to the learning algorithm), the gap between generalization error of hypothesis h and error on validation samples should be bounded by a value that decreases as number of samples increase.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer in the same book:

> The cross validation method often works very well in practice.
>   However,it might sometime fail, as the artiﬁcial example shows.
>   Rigorously understanding the exact behavior of cross validation is
>   still an **open problem**. Rogers and Wagner (Rogers & Wagner 1978)
>   have shown that for k local rules (e.g., k Nearest Neighbor) the cross
>   validation procedure gives a very good estimate of the true error.
>   Other papers show that cross validation works for stable algorithms.