# Repeating CV multiple times

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, cross-validation, cart

I understood the purpose behind CV (i.e. just to make sure the data is spread well across the folds, and the skewness is somewhat averaged-out).

Let's take this example -

```
cv_cart_Scores=[]
for k in myList:
    cart = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 777, min_samples_leaf=k)
    cart_scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(cart, x_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
    cv_cart_scores.append(cart_scores.mean())
```

Here, `cv_scores` stores the accuracy score of each fold in the CV. And later we mean it in next line.
I'm not getting:

1. What is the purpose of `cv_cart_scores`.
2. What is the purpose of looping it `myList` number of times?
3. Shall we take `cv_cart_scores.mean()` at last to get the final score of the model?

RB (on Python 3.6)

Comment: Since you say that you are familiar with cross-validation, your question seems to boil down to ["how to choose between hold out vs k-fold cross-validation"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104713/hold-out-validation-vs-cross-validation), am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you posted appears to be a procedure using 10-fold CV to select a value for the `min_samples_leaf` hyperparameter.

1. `cv_cart_scores` is storing the CV scores for each setting of `min_samples_leaf`
2. `myList` appears to be a list that stores different possible values for `min_samples_leaf` that this code would like to test. The goal is to find the value that gives the best CV performance.
3. No. You will use the index value of the highest accuracy score in the `cv_cart_scores` list to tell you which index of `myList` stores the best value for the `min_samples_leaf` hyperparameter.

Comment: Oh yes! Do you mean the code snippet above is a step towards hyperparameter tuning? I liked your explanation though. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Yes. It is using 10-fold CV to do hyperparameter tuning for the `min_samples_leaf` hyperparameter.