# Quasi/Complete separation due to huge and infinite values

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, roc, separation, quasi-likelihood

(R statistics)

My question is regarding [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) warning. My data contains patients and healthy subjects. Exponential decay is my outcome measure.

I have a example dataset [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0bd69f858bc5115e20e0c9d7757b3d3620190627194143/037c45)

I managed to run bayesglm and firth method with brglm. 
However, I wanted to try the regular glm while this is easier to write down in a paper.

I found out that because of the high numbers >100 seconds, the quasi separation warning arises (kinda makes sense, while the slope of propability will exceed a near vertical line).

To test this, I calculated the mean + (6*std) of the healthy subjects and replaced the values of the patients exceeding this value with this value. Now the warnings are gone.

They more or less give the same ROC-curve as the bayesglm and firth's method.

However, I do not know if this is a valid method to "arbitrarily" change values. Maybe non-parametric ranking is in place instead of using the actual values to undermine this problem or changing it to log values.

Hope somebody can give me a valid solution in order to write my paper.

Moreover, how do I present values that are infinite, like mean+/-SD is not possible ofcourse! Thanks in advance!

Data:

column [1]= Type (healthy=0,patient=1).

column [2]= decay.

column [3]= if the value is higer than mean(health)+(6*std(health)) it was replaced by this value.

````
# STACK EXCHANGE
library("caret")
library("ROCR")
library("readxl")

stackdata <- read_excel("STACK.xlsx",sheet = "DATA")
stackdata$type <- as.factor(stackdata$type)
levels(stackdata$type)<-c('H','P')
head(stackdata)

set.seed(777)
partitionRule<-createDataPartition(stackdata$type,p=0.7,list=F)
trainingSet<-stackdata[partitionRule,]
testingSet<-stackdata[-partitionRule,]
splitRule<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE, number=5, p=0.7, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, returnResamp = "all") 

## GLM with extreme values
glmModel<-train(type~decay,data=stackdata,method="glm",family=binomial(logit),trControl=splitRule, metric="ROC")
glmTest<-predict(glmModel,newdata=testingSet,type="raw")
confusionMatrix(data=glmTest,testingSet$type)


ROC_glmModel <- roc(as.numeric(glmModel$trainingData$.outcome=='P'),aggregate(P~rowIndex,glmModel$pred,mean)[,'P'])
ROC_mean95_plot <- plot.roc(ROC_glmModel$response,ROC_glmModel$predictor) 
Youden_coords_mean95 <- coords(ROC_mean95_plot, "b", ret="t", best.method="youden")


## GLM   mean+(6*std) of the healthy subjects
glmModel<-train(type~decay6std,data=stackdata,method="glm",family=binomial(logit),trControl=splitRule, metric="ROC")
glmTest<-predict(glmModel,newdata=testingSet,type="raw")
confusionMatrix(data=glmTest,testingSet$type)


ROC_glmModel <- roc(as.numeric(glmModel$trainingData$.outcome=='P'),aggregate(P~rowIndex,glmModel$pred,mean)[,'P'])
ROC_mean95_plot <- plot.roc(ROC_glmModel$response,ROC_glmModel$predictor) 
Youden_coords_mean95 <- coords(ROC_mean95_plot, "b", ret="t", best.method="youden")

```
````

Comment: Could you please say more about the goal of your study? If it is to characterize the difference between patients and normals in terms of `decay` then you might consider analyzing this as a survival model, with `decay` the response variable and `patient/normal` as the predictor.

Comment: Hi EdM! thanks on your response! In this case it is to diagnose, so if subject X has a decay (I mean by decay the tau-value of a monoexponential function) of e.g.12 seconds, I want to know if it is a patient or a healthy subjects. Therefore, I want a ROC model with a confusionmatrix

Comment: Is the `decay` the only predictor that you have for distinguishing healthy/patient, or are there additional predictors (e.g., age, sex, BMI,...) that you intend to include in your model?

Comment: For the ease of the question not. But maybe I want to put them in a e.g. stepwise/backward regression. For now it's just to figure out the right method to start with. Do you have a opinion how to deal with this "problem".

Answer (score 1):

If you were only interested in `decay` as a single predictor of `patient/normal` status, then this problem would disappear if you use `decay` non-parametrically. Just rank order the cases by `decay` values and plot true-positive fractions against false-positive fractions for each `decay` value as a cutoff in sequence to get a receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve. You can then choose any specific cutoff that you wish for a confusion matrix. There is no need for a logistic regression and potential problems with complete separation.

As a comment says that you intend to include `decay` as only one among several predictors, however, you need to find a way to combine it with the other predictors to get an overall linear predictor of the log-odds of `patient/normal` status.

From what you describe, the problem might arise from your attempt to use `decay` as an untransformed predictor. With some individual decay times more than 6 standard deviations above the mean in the original scale of seconds, it seems unlikely that the log-odds of `patient/normal` would be linearly related to untransformed `decay` values. Yet that is the hidden assumption in the way you are modeling `decay`.

So I recommend trying different transformations of the `decay` values to find one that bears a better linear relationship to log-odds of `patient/normal`. Consider a logarithmic transformation, some other [power transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform), or maybe even an inverse transformation so that the high-value outliers get bunched close to 0.

A few more notes:

First, it's possible that your perfect separation is real and that there is some value of `decay` that perfectly distinguishes patients from normals. If that's the case, your problem is again solved non-parametrically. Check that possibility.

Second, I would recommend against the stepwise selection of predictors that you describe in a comment. Recall that logistic regression has an inherent [omitted-variable bias](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113766/28500) so that your coefficient values will be biased if you thus remove from your model any predictor that is related to `patient/normal` status. Provided that you have on the order of 15 of the lower of `patient` or `normal` [cases per predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26016/28500) you shouldn't be in danger of overfitting. It's better to use knowledge of the subject matter rather than stepwise to choose predictors if you have fewer cases than that.

Third, unless you have an extremely large number (hundreds to thousands) of cases, the use of separate training and test sets suggested in your code may limit your power. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/104713/28500) for discussion. Using the entire data set with cross-validation or bootstrapping might be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'll dive in the material.