# Bootstrapping the pipeline itself

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, bootstrap

Generally, I've been taught that the `test` set should not be touched by any means, but suppose I have a pipeline that:

1. First split data into `training` and `test`; and
2. A second split occurs on the `training` set, which can either be a `train/dev` split or a k cross-validation to do hyperparameters search;
3. Then with the optimal hyperparameters obtained in 2. I do the fit on the train set in 1.

Now I would like to assess the "robustness" of this pipeline, should I bootstrap the entire `train/test` split N times and rerun the pipeline, or it suffices to bootstrap directly from the `test` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) bootstrap the `train`/`test` split (aka the "outer" split).

> the `test` set should not be touched by any means

The point is that the test data needs to be independent of *all* data that entered the training process in *any* way. Hyperparameter tuning (selecting based on intermediate test results on the `dev` set) is part of the training process.

Not touching (looking into) the `test` set prevents one important way of violating independence: the `test` set entering the training process by driving decisions about the training.

However, there are other ways how independence may be violated (by structure in the data), and [sometimes setting a `test` set away [possibly even in a physical fashion] once can be a good way to ensure that independence wrt. to  factors that could violate independence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/104713/4598).

However, if you obtain the `test` set by (randomly) splitting the initially available data set, there is nothing that should keep you from repeating this process to assess the stability of the whole procedure: the single `test` set isn't any more independent of the training data than the repeated `test` sets are.
If you move to a cross validation procedure for this split, you get what is called nested cross validation, with the outer and inner split both being done via cross validation.

Bootstrapping or rather, out-of-bootstrap testing for the outer split uses drawing with replacement for the `train` set and is thus *not* the repeated version of the usual `train`/`test` split which uses drawing without replacement.
There is nothing wrong with using this approach, but it should be clearly marked that there is this difference in the sampling procedure which does affect the model.